# Alias a method to a single object

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaprogramming

I'm trying to define a singleton aliased method.
As in:

```
name = 'Bob'
# I want something similar to this to work
name.define_singleton_method(:add_cuteness, :+)
name = name.add_cuteness 'by'
```

I'm sure I can pass a method object as a second parameter.

I wouldn't want to do it like this

```
name.define_singleton_method(:add_cuteness) { |val| self + val }
```

I want to alias the `String#+` method not use it.
Emphasis on alias, but sending the actual method object as a second parameter would be cool too.

Comment: you can't `define_singleton_method` on an Integer it is immutable

Comment: @bjhaid true. I changed it to `String`

Comment: `name = 'Bob'; name.define_singleton_method(:add_cuteness, &name.method(:+)); name = name.add_cuteness 'by' #=> 'Bobby'` is this what you want?

Comment: I knew I would be able to send the method as a second parameter. This is most likely what I will use however I accepted @ndn's answer since it uses actual aliasing and a good explanation.

Comment: `&name.method(:+)` is technically not correct because `&` is syntactic sugar for `to_proc`. So it converts the `String#+` to something similar to `{ |val| self + val }` which is what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Singleton methods are contained in that object's singleton class:

```
class Object
  def define_singleton_alias(new_name, old_name)
    singleton_class.class_eval do
      alias_method new_name, old_name
    end
  end
end

rob = 'Rob'
bob = 'Bob'
bob.define_singleton_alias :add_cuteness, :+

bob.add_cuteness 'by' # => "Bobby"
rob.add_cuteness 'by' # => NoMethodError
```

---

`Object#define_singleton_method` basically does something like this:

```
def define_singleton_method(name, &block)
  singleton_class.class_eval do
    define_method name, &block
  end
end
```

Comment: As is oft the case, [Module#alias_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) permits its arguments to be symbols or strings: `bob.add_cuteness 'by' #=> "Bobby"`.